# How to autoshare on facebook and twitter in ios 6?

Tags: iphone, facebook, twitter, share

I m using facebook and twitter share in my application ,here i want to share the default link and text without shows the share windows,i tried many ways but still i did not get the solution.

this is my code:

```
 NSString *str_face=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Another insta from Dealnabit just claimed now, Got yours now"];
 SLComposeViewController *facebookPostVC =[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook ];

[facebookPostVC addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];

[facebookPostVC setInitialText:str_face];

[self presentViewController:facebookPostVC animated:YES completion:Nil];`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.For Facebook using Accounts Framework and SLRequest of Social Framework without dialogue

```
-(void)Post
{
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

ACAccountType *facebookAccountType = [self.accountStore 
    accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

// Specify App ID and permissions
NSDictionary *options = @{
      ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"my app id",
      ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
      ACFacebookAudeinceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
};

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:facebookAccountType 
      options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
        if (granted) {
            NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore 
                    accountsWithAccountType:facebookAccountType];
            facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle Failure
        }
}];

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"message": @"test post"};

NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

SLRequest *feedRequest = [SLRequest 
        requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
        requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST 
        URL:feedURL 
        parameters:parameters];

    feedRequest.account = self.facebookAccount;

    [feedRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, 
           NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
    {
        // Handle response
    }];
}
```

1. Twitter Post iOS6 without dialogue

   ```
     -(void)PostToTwitter
     {

    ACAccountStore *account = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [account accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:   
   ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

   [account requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil 
          completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
    if (granted == YES)
    {
         NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [account 
                accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

         if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
         {
           ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts lastObject];

           NSDictionary *message = @{@"status": @”Test Twitter post from iOS 6”};

           NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL 
            URLWithString:@"http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json"];

           SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest 
               requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
                      requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                      URL:requestURL parameters:message];
         }
    }];
     }
      }
   ```

Comment: its not working application get crashed, please give any example app link.

Comment: strange cause its working at my end, anyways check out this http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/sites/default/files/TempFBapp.zip

Comment: @ant_one If you'd like to post your working solution, please post a new answer instead of modifying an old one.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Twitter example post is missing to perform the request:

```
 // Post the request
 [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

 // Block handler to manage the response
 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
      {
       NSLog(@"Twitter response, HTTP response: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]);
      }];
```

And I would use the latest version of API and https:

```
NSURL *requestURL = [NSURLURLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"];
```